# Is there any inter-process in-memory storage for node?

Tags: node.js, process, shared-memory

Let's say I want to share some context (simply some string) between two processes. I could do it with a file (fs.writeFile/readFile), but disk is slow. Is there any way to store context in memory? Is Redis (I am not familiar with it) suitable for this task? Isn't it too heavy for this, is there something very-very lightweight?

P.S. IPC and any other *asynchronous* inter-process communication is not suitable.

Comment: Take a look to https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback, questions like too heavy/suitable it depends of you requirements

Comment: You can try Sphinx. It's a full text search engine. Not really designed for your case scenario described, but could work, you can communicate with it using any MYSQL compatible driver, in this case, the MySQL or Mysql2 modules. It's very fast and very lightweight, I can index 100.000, 5 row-character varying items in less than 20MB of memory, and the queries usually take less than 0,01ms to return.

Comment: @rkmax that's asynchronous, which is not suitable unfortunately (as I said)

Comment: @NickLeBlanc I guess it's even heavier overhead than redis, since it has to have all the search-related functionality

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Not really, as long as you don't use those functions you're gonna be fine, Sphinx built in mechanisms for direct ID matching are very performant and very low overhead, you could check some benchmarks and docs online for more info. Regardless, if you could offer us more information on your needs maybe we could suggest something more appropriate.